# <Pre> rendering difference between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, svelte

I am working on a guitar chord app and the problem is Firefox is not rendering paragraphs as expected.

Firefox is render `p` tags with extra space on both bottom and top.
There is no padding, nor margin. Firefox says there is just "gap" between the elements. I am super surprised...[image]
Please note that I have highlighted two sibling `p` elements, and the there is nothing between them.
Here is my structure:

```css
    p {
        margin: 0; padding: 0;    
    }
```

```html
<pre>
    <section style="inline-block">(Song metadata, you can see example in the screenshot)</section>
    <p>chords</p>
    <p>a line of lyrics</p>
    <p>chords</p>
    <p>a line of lyrics</p>
    <p>chords</p>
    <p>a line of lyrics</p>
    <p>chords</p>
    <p>a line of lyrics</p>
    <p>chords</p>
    <p>a line of lyrics</p>
    ...
</pre>
```

Expected (from `Chrome`): [image: Expected]

`Firefox`: [image: Unexpected from Firefox]

Firefox screenshot, `p` element boundaries
[image: Firefox screenshot, p element boundaries]

I tried those:

- Changing `margin`,`padding` of the both `pre` and `p` elements
- Changing `display` css prop on both elements
- Setting `p`'s style to `line-height: 0.6em` works, but it is not a solution.

#EDIT 1: Forgot to add stylesheet. btw, there is no margin, nor padding. I added image to show boundary of `p` element.

#EDIT 2: Added what I've tried

Comment: Why not just explicitly set the padding/margin for `pre p` elements?

Comment: I have set both margin, padding to  zero.
I forgot to add `style`, now I edited the post and appended it. Ty

Comment: View this on your Browser Inspector and see if anything is overwriting your CSS declaration for the padding of the `<p>` element

Comment: in between each <p> you have a line-break, firefox treat your <p> and that line-break as a block element  , chrome doesn't . <pre> or white-space:pre will do the same

Comment: Because your code is inside a `<pre>` tag; the whitespace is also given a volume

Comment: best is probably to use white-space on the p tags and a monospace font .

Comment: I use monospace font actually. Making each `p`'s style to `white-space: pre` made it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid.

A `p` element is **not** allowed to be a child of a `pre` element.

The inconsistency you see is the result of browsers trying to recover from your error in different ways.

Remove the `p` elements. Put line breaks in the source code instead.